# C# How to treat static class as a variable

Tags: c#, class, variables, static, public

I have a static Class and within it I have multiple public static attributes. I treat this class as my global class.

However now I need to treat this class as a variable so that I can pass it to a method of another class for processing..

I can't instantiate this class.. So in effect I can only assign the variables inside this class.

Is my understanding correct or am I missing something?

```
public static class Global
{
    public const int RobotMax = 2;

    // GUI sync context
    public static MainForm mainForm;
    public static SynchronizationContext UIContext;

    // Database
    public static Database DB = null;
    public static string localDBName = "local.db";
    public static Database localDB = null;
    public static Database ChangeLogDB = null;
    public static string changeLogDBName = "ChangeLog.db";
 }
```

Let say I have a class like this, and I need to somehow keep a copy of this in another class maybe

```
public static class Global_bk
{
    public const int RobotMax = 2;

    // GUI sync context
    public static MainForm mainForm;
    public static SynchronizationContext UIContext;

    // Database
    public static Database DB = null;
    public static string localDBName = "local.db";
    public static Database localDB = null;
    public static Database ChangeLogDB = null;
    public static string changeLogDBName = "ChangeLog.db";
 }
```

I need to copy the contents from Global to Global_bk.

And after that I need to compare the contents of the two classes in a method like

```
static class extentions
{
    public static List<Variance> DetailedCompare<T>(T val1, T val2)
    {
        List<Variance> variances = new List<Variance>();
        FieldInfo[] fi = val1.GetType().GetFields();
        foreach (FieldInfo f in fi)
        {
            Variance v = new Variance();
            v.Prop = f.Name;
            v.valA = f.GetValue(val1);
            v.valB = f.GetValue(val2);
            if (!v.valA.Equals(v.valB))
                variances.Add(v);

        }
        return variances;
    }
}

class Variance
{
    string _prop;
    public string Prop
    {
        get { return _prop; }
        set { _prop = value; }
    }
    object _valA;
    public object valA
    {
        get { return _valA; }
        set { _valA = value; }
    }
    object _valB;
    public object valB
    {
        get { return _valB; }
        set { _valB = value; }
    }
}
```

So on my main form, how do I go about calling the compare method and passing the static Global class inside?

example: extentions.DetailedCompare(Global, Global_bk) ? Of course this would give me an error because I cant pass a type as a variable.

Please help me, this is driving me nuts...

Comment: Next time do reduce your question and example to as little as possible needed to show the question. You have like 7 static fields to divert focus from what you Really are asking about. That said, your very question was well written.

Answer (score 2):

How about the singleton pattern ? You can pass reference to shared interface (IDoable in exable below) and still have just one instance.

I.E.:

```
public interface IDoable {
  int Value { get; set; }
  void Foo();
}

public static class DoableWrapper {
  private MyDoable : IDoable {
    public int Value { get;set; }
    public void Foo() {
    }
  }

  private static IDoable s_Doable = new MyDoable();
  public static IDoable Instance {
    get { return s_Doable; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Singleton is the way to go here. You can do it like this:

```
internal class SomeClass
{
   private static SomeClass singleton;

   private SomeClass(){}  //yes: private constructor

   public static SomeClass GetInstance()
   {
        return singleton ?? new SomeClass();
   }

    public int SomeProperty {get;set;}

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        //do something
    }
 }
```

The GetInstance Method will return you a SomeClass object that you can edit and pass into whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the members with classname.membername.

```
internal static class SomeClass
{
    public static int SomeProperty {get;set;}

    public static void SomeMethod()
    {
        //do something
    }
 }

 static void main()
 {
     SomeClass.SomeProperty = 15;
     SomeClass.SomeMethod();
 }
```

Comment: Right of course. But how do i access the class itself which as all the members/variable etc?

Comment: All members of static classes are static... if you want to access them make them public or internal. Then use the classes name . Member  (methods properties...)

Comment: Yes i understand that too. It is public. But I need to pass the class itself as a variable into a argument of a function/member. I dont want to pass each variable/member/property/attribute individually. I essentially want to copy its contents to another identical class so that I can compare between the two.

Comment: now that is something you cannot do with static classes. there are no objects of static classes. But you can still have static members in normal classes.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you are going to obtain a variable with the "class" information is using reflection. You can get a Type object for the class.

```
namespace Foo {

public class Bar
{
}

}


Type type = Type.GetType("Foo.Bar");
```

Otherwise, if you are really describing a class "instance" then use an object and simply instantiate one.

C# offers no other notation for class variables.